# Why do the 2 half-angle identities for tangent not produce identical solutions for this equation?

Tags: trigonometry

Interested to know why these equivalent identities do not produce identical solutions...
[tan(x/2)-sinx = 0 solutions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WMDc.jpg)

Comment: When you simplify $\sin x$ from both sides in the first method, you neglected the solutions for $\sin x = 0 \land \cos x \ne -1$. Also, please type out your question if possible

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)